# Setting the width of a relative div isn't working

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web project and I have a popup b ox that allows the user to type in some text and this text is then appened onto the end of a content editable and the text is within span class.

I want the width to be 80% and the text to wrap but the width is being ignored and the text is all bunched up and over lapping each line.

Below is what it looks like.

[image: Div not setting width]

And below is the css..

```
font-style: italic;
background-color: #ababab;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
height: auto;
width: 80%;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is in a span, it will default to being an inline element. Inline elements do not respect height and width properties. Inline elements however will respect line-height, and this property will fix your overlapping issue.

```
line-height: 20px;
```

To get your element to respect width, you will need to change the display on the element to inline-block or block.

```
display: inline-block;
display: block;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot about the display: block